# search value in the entire table oracle sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have table `test_d` which has 30 `columns` and i want to search for specific string value 'ARFTU' to check in which `column` does this value exists and i want to get entire row.

As i dont want to use below `sql` to check each and every columns to see if the value exists, Is there any other way to write sql which checks the entire columns in table and search for specific value ?

```
SELECT * from test_d
WHERE name ='ARFTU'
```

Comment: I think you have a problem with your data model.  It sounds like you have 30 columns with similar information.  These should probably be separate rows in an association/junction table.

Comment: no not similar information there are columns which has number, date, varchar datatype but as this is string value which i want to search so may be i will check for only carchar datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your columns have compatible data types and you just want to return any rows that have at least one column that matches your value here is one way to accomplish that:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_d
WHERE 'ARFTU' IN (col1, col2, ... coln);
```

<sub>[check](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159608/176644)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM test_d WHERE 'ARFTU' IN (col1, col2, ...., col30);